# Second monitor on left side with Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

With Windows 7 it is easy to have the 2nd monitor on the left side, but can't find how to get this with my new computer running Windows 8.  It allows me to extend to the right side but not to the left side.  How can this be changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is very similar to Windows 7 if you don't use the "Settings" app as suggested by the Microsoft Windows site.

From your Start screen, open "Desktop". Right-click on your desktop background and select "Screen Resolution". It will show a picture of your monitor setup, with numbers showing on each one to show its placement. If you only see one monitor in the picture, ensure that you have selected "Extend my display" to have both screens operational, and click "apply" to make the setting active. By clicking "Identify", the numbers will appear on the actual screens to assist you with which monitor is which.

You can then click-and-drag the picture of the monitor with the number 2 on it to the left of the monitor with the number 1 on it, and click "apply" again. You can also adjust the placement for different heights of monitors, or even "stack" two monitors on top of one another.

If you have a graphics card with advanced features (NVidia, AMD), you may need to consult the manual for your graphics card for specific instructions for other advanced features.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the answer already given.

A nice tip to include in it:

you also can drag the fir or second window at centre vertically for more productive environment and less confusion of going to other screen when you try to click small desktop at right bottom corner to minimize all windows.

Hope you like it.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).